# Cordova - Adding plugins results to my code getting deleted

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Pretty straight forward as what the title suggests.

I have a cordova app that i'm writing (cause I'm trying to learn it) with an android platform. I'm using android studio to do the editing. One funny thing is that every time I add a new plugin, the code gets reset to the beginning.

Does this have anything to do with the www at the root of the project? I have 2 "www" folders. One at the root of the project and the other inside platform/android/assets.

Note that I am editing the one under platform/android.

Comment: yeah, you have to edit the root www folder, not the platform/android folder

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line for building and running the app, the root www-folder and some other things, like icons, splashscreens, are copied to the platform folder(s). So this folder will be overridden.

The faster way for developing an app with cordova is to have a symlink from the root www-folder to the www-platform-folder.

I do the coding with PhpStorm, it has a better support for JS/CSS and HTML than Android Studio and do the platform specific things like building, running and special settings in Xcode and Android Studio.

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks Joerg!